# Which configuration is better for this electric motor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, torque

I have a problem with this exercise, it's an electric motor.
an electric motor works because of a magnet, and a wire with a current (i.e electrons moving in it). by turning on and off the current it's possible to switch north pole with south pole of the magnet and this allow a rotor to rotate. [explained simply, it's just to have an idea of how an electric motor works, in order to solve the exercise].

exercise asks to find which configuration of this motor gives a better maximum torque (i.e bigger power).

first configuration: $$l_2 = 4\space l_1, l_1 + l_2 = l \space$$
second configuration: $$l_2 = 2\space l_1, \space l_1 + l_2 = l$$

I've posted the photo of how the electric motor looks like, I know it could be difficult to understand, but it's the image of the exercise.
I have no clue. I don't know how to start. I know that an electric motor works thanks to Lorentz force and Faraday's law, but I don't know how to apply them in an exercise like this one.

EDIT: I think I've solved it, if $l_2$ is longer, then Lorentz force makes the rotor run faster. But I need to formalize this concept. for now, final solution is the first configuration. does it make sense?

[image: this is how the electric motor looks like]

Comment: *better maximum torque $<\ne >$ bigger power*

Comment: I thought that if a car has a higher maximum torque, then it has a higher power

Comment: [It can be shown](https://www.schoolphysics.co.uk/age16-19/Electricity%20and%20magnetism/Electromagnetism/text/Torque_on_a_coil/index.html) that the maximum torque for a simple dc motor is proportional to the area of the coil. So what you need to do is find which configuration has the bigger area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is some things that need to be cleared up. If $l_1$ is longer is means that the electric motor will create more torque since the force from the lorentz force will be further from the axis of the motor. That would mean that for this example $l_2=2l_1$ would have the motor generating the most torque.

There are other things that would have an impact on this like how close the windings in the motor are to the magnetic fields but if that is all the same the larger moment in the winding should produce the most torque.